# Clean-URL -> URL's with only 1 parameter works, but with more than 1 parameter CSS-file will not be included

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing, clean-urls

I use Clean-URL in my project. For simplicity i simplified the code.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

My index.php:

```
<?php
    
    require_once "/login.php";
        
?>
```

The .css-file include in the HTML-part in the login.php:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My project structure:

In the root-folder "test" are the index.php, login.php and the bootstrap-directory.

### And now my problem:

If I request a URL with only 1 Parameter like

```
http://localhost/test/bla then all working!
```

But if i request a URL with 2 Paramter like:

```
http://localhost/test/bla/bla
```

then the login-page is showing, but without all the css-styles (css-file was not included...).

But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if your htaccess is in `test` folder, it should look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then, you also have to add a rewrite base (for absolute path with many virtual directories) for your css and js links

```
<link href="/test/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But you could simply use this in your html page and keep your css/js links unchanged

```
<base href="/test/" />
```

Comment: Tank's a lot! (base-tag was not necessary).

Comment: You're welcome. Like i said it is not necessary, it only avoids you to repeat `/test/` in each css/js links.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're including your css with a relative url, so you're actually trying to load

```
http://server.com/test/bla/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

instead of

```
http://server.com/test/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

this isn't a clean URL issue. Quick way to deal with it:

```
<link href="/test/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

after all, for a given project, the assets directory is not prone to change often.